# How to define globally constant variable Date.now() depend to current time of request in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I have a constant like this:

```
export const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 10,
  filterContents: '',
  dateRange: {
     fromDate: moment().subtract(15, 'days'),
     toDate: moment()
  }
}
```

The problem here is `DEFAULT_OPTIONS` just only declares one time. So when I request to the server, `fromDate` and `toDate` always have values that are the same as the first time define. It does not depend on the current time of the request.

**So, how to define a Date.now() depend on request in NodeJS?**

*Note: I don't want to change from a variable to a function.*

Comment: make DEFAULT_OPTIONS into a function that returns the object

Comment: Make a Request object which holds all relevant request dependent values, such as the Date.now(). Everytime a request arrives, the request is passed down the stream with the Request object being relevant to the handlers. I don't know the structure of your setup, but thats how I'd do it

Comment: I just noticed the note. Honestly, your request doesn't make sense with that note. You can't have DEFAULT_OPTIONS as an object, with properties that change like that.

Answer (score 1):

On second thought, you may actually be able to use javascript getters for this:

```
let dateRange = {
  get fromDate() {
    return moment().subtract(15, 'days')
  },

  get toDate() {
    return moment()
  }
}

let DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 10,
  filterContents: '',
  dateRange: dateRange
}
```

as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Answer (score 0):

make it into a function

```
export const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = () => ({
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 10,
  filterContents: '',
  dateRange: {
     fromDate: moment().subtract(15, 'days'),
     toDate: moment()
  }
})
```

and then when you want to use the default options, call the function, `DEFAULT_OPTIONS()`